Noun modifier in this sentence "自分がされて嫌なこと"
So I now what this sentence means but if I were to write it it would have been 自分がされる嫌なこと instead.
May someone please explain to me why its better to use the  Te-Form (されて) and not dictionary form (される) for the verb? It would be great if you could also include some reference so I can kinda read about it.
Thanks!

Both are grammatical, but されて indicates a cause-effect relationship regardless of the tense, whereas される indicates a future tense.

自分がされて嫌なこと
things that you/I/one dislike when done to them
自分がされる嫌なこと
the undesirable thing that will be done to you/me/one

Practically, 自分がされて嫌なこと refers to undesirable things in general, but 自分がされる嫌なこと means it will actually happen. In the following sentence, you can only use されて嫌なこと because this is a general advice.

自分がされて嫌なことを人にするな。
Don't do things you would dislike when they were done to you.


Thanks! Alright so when modifying nouns.......Te-Form = General saying.....Dictionary-Form = Will actually happen
